# how can i call method of class outiside the class javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var Card = YClass.extend({
 // define Class Name
 className:'Card', 
 // class level default options
 config:{
  id:'cardid', 
  container:'body',   // id of container in which to render the user
  render:false,
  template: 'tmpl_card',  // id of template used to render user
  debug:false   
 },
setposition:function() {
  var i=1;
  var xpos=10;
  var ypos=15;
  var recvflag=false;
}
);
```

how i can call set position function i am trying by Card.setposition();

but its giving me error that setposition is not defined 
why??

Comment: please format your code a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a jQuery thing, it's a YClass thing. I don't know what YClass is, but my guess is that it defines *classes*, which you then make *instances* of:

```
var c = new Card();
c.setposition();
```

This would be similar to Resig's "[Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)" `Class` thing, Prototype's [`Class`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/class/) object, or the system I [describe here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html).

If you just want a container with some functions on it, you can just do that directly:

```
var Card = {
    setposition: function() {
        alert("Hi there!");
    };
};
Card.setposition(); // alerts "Hi there!"
```

...but I'm guessing you're using YClass for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should call like this:

```
Card.prototype.setPosition();
```

**WHY:**

In JavaScript properties(fields) of *Class* is stored in *Class*.**prototype** Object. When instance of *Class* is created this instance has properties that are in *Class*.**prototype** Object. This means that instance calls *Class*.**prototype**.method when you call *instance*.method, it doesn't have its own. And if you want to call method of *Class* without instantiation, you should invoke directly from its **prototype** Object.

Comment: Why did you give me minus? :)